# Recommendation in Video Analysis with Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

I recently took a course at Neural Networks and decided to do research work. What I have considered is designing a network that recognizes the movement of the lips, which is commonly known as **lip-reading**.

I know the theory about neural networks, I chose to design a **Convolutional neural network** but I have **problems** thinking about how to extract the characteristics of the *video* or *sequence of images* that will serve as input to the network that I plan to design.

Before focusing on the full investigation, I wanted to be helped a bit by giving me concepts or ideas on how to do it, mainly in the **feature extraction part**.

What I have thought in general is the following:

A vowel or syllable lasts approximately 1 to 2 seconds in video. From that video I have to extract a sequence of images that show how the lips move. Assuming I selected about 10 or 15 images, I suppose all those images, after being processed, should be my "input" to get the characteristics.

But I have already analyzed a single image, like the classic example of "Recognize a letter" but, as I said before, I suppose I will have a sequence of images to analyze and that confuses me a bit.

I would like to know if I'm on the right track with this idea and if not, I would they to guide me with this. I hope I have been clear with the aforementioned, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This paper should help you decide how to handle the sequence of frames as input to a neural network. Looks like you can concatenate(combine) all of the frames for a particular sound into one image and feed into your net for training and evaluation.

http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2016/pdfs/217_Report.pdf